# Является ли "этою" словарным словом?

Tags: лексикография

Помните песню? **"Я не знаю, что мне делать с *этою* бедой".**

Answer (score 1):

Это не словарное слово, это местоимение с вариативным окончанием -ой/ою  - следствие редукции гласного, в некоторых формах она носит факультативный характер:

В окончании тв. п. ед. ч. существительных 1-го склонения утрачивается гласный [у]: вод-ою > вод-ой, гор-ою > гор-ой, земл-ёю > земл-ёй, слуг-ою > слуг-ой, нош-ею >нош-ей, то есть [ojу] > [oj]; [еjу] > [еj].

Это справедливо и для окончаний тв. п. ед. ч. жен. рода неличных местоимений и полных прилагательных – тою > той, молодою > молодой; а также для окончания тв. п. ед. ч. личных и возвратного местоимений – мною > мной, собою > собой.

В русском языке до сих пор параллельно употребляются варианты окончания -ой / -ою. Предпочтительна  форма с окончанием -ОЙ.Формы же с окончанием -ОЮ являются устаревшими и широко употребляются в речи поэтической.

Answer (score 0):

Раз есть в словарях - значит является словарным (см например Викисловарь)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

На сколько я знаю, это слова с песни Виагры - украинской музыкальной групы. Думаю это и есть причина появления нового слова. По-украински, это слово заканчивается именно на букву "ю" - `цією`. Вполне возможно, что это можно назвать легкой формой суржика.

Answer (score -1):

Думаю, что это устаревшее или просторечное слово, которое употребляют до сих пор.